# How to manipulate more files in bash containing the same string in their filename?

Tags: bash

I have 100 files with the filenames like these:

```
asdf_01, asdf_02, asdf_03, asdf_04, asdf_05, etc. 

dfgh_01, dfgh_02, dfgh_03, dfgh_04, dfgh_05, etc.
```

I'd like to paste files with the same ending, like this:

```
paste asdf_01 dfgh_01 > pasted_01
```

How to apply this command for all files?

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in {00..99}; do
    paste "asdf_$i" "dfgh_$i" > "pasted_$i"
done
```

Answer (score -1):

Basically you can use the following glob expression:

```
paste *_01 > pasted_01
```

To iterate trough all the possible values you need a loop:

```
for suffix in {01..99} ; do
    # Check if there are exactly two files with that suffix
    if [ $(($(find -name "*${suffix}" -printf . | wc -c))) -eq 2 ] ; then
        paste *_"${suffix}" > pasted_"${suffix}"
    fi
done
```